# How do I select a page using views_embed_view?

Tags: views

I am writing a rather intensive ajax interface that requires me to manhandle views quite a bit. I am retrieving the results of the ajax triggers using

```
views_embed_view($view, $display, $arg1, $arg2);
```

Everything works great except the default pager ajax drops the custom info I'm dumping into `views_embed_view`

How can I use views_embed_view to select which pager page to return?

drupal 7, views 3

Comment: Are asking about how to do this in views on in your ajax code?

Comment: This is all php code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after a good deal of research and testing.

[`views_embed_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7.x-3.x) does not have a way to do this. However, we can use the same method that `views_embed_view()` used.

```
1  $view_args = array($terms); //, $search_text
2  $view_object = views_get_view($view_name);
3  $view_object->set_current_page($offset);
4  $html = $view_object->preview($view_display, $view_args);
```

Line 1,2, and 3 are a simplified version of `views_embed_view()`. I'm bypassing permissions here so check out the function code to see how to do that part.

Line 3 is the part that sets the pager offset and solves my problem.

Note: their are two functions for setting the page offset and I used the wrong one the first time and it caused a log of confusion. The first function `view->set_offset` does not seem to work. I think it sets the correct value in the view object but without doing the theme and query work. so `view->set_current_page` is the one you want to use. I think it goes through the pager plugin to set the query and theme implications as well as set the offset.